# SQL Query for current state of all entities in event table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that contains event data for N number of devices, each of which may or may not be adding data to the table at a given time.  I need to query the table for the last status of each distinct device in table, as well as the prior status of the device.

Example table data:

```
id   | device    | event_data  | date_time
________________________________________________
1019 | sensor501 | open        | 2018-01-05T00:05:15Z
1020 | sensor509 | closed      | 2018-01-05T00:05:16Z
1021 | sensor501 | reset       | 2018-01-05T00:05:18Z
1022 | sensor501 | closed      | 2018-01-05T00:05:19Z
1023 | sensor974 | open        | 2018-01-05T00:05:27Z
1024 | sensor729 | closed      | 2018-01-05T00:06:07Z
1025 | sensor729 | reset       | 2018-01-05T00:06:46Z
```

Example result data:

```
device    | event_data  | prev_event_data | date_time
________________________________________________
sensor501 | closed      | reset           | 2018-01-05T00:05:19Z
sensor509 | closed      | null            | 2018-01-05T00:05:16Z
sensor974 | open        | null            | 2018-01-05T00:05:27Z
sensor729 | reset       | closed          | 2018-01-05T00:06:46Z
```

How would you, in the most efficient way, query the example table to get the example result data?

Comment: What SQL engine do you use?

Comment: @juergend it is a variant of MySQL

Comment: Incidentally this is the most frequently asked question under this tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with correlated sub-queries. First to get the latest event_data and then one more to get the previous row of the latest.

```
select t1.device,t1.event_data,t1.date_time,
(select t2.event_data from tbl t2 
 where t1.device=t2.device and t1.date_time>t2.date_time 
 order by t2.date_time desc limit 1) as prev_event_data
from tbl t1
where t1.date_time = (select max(t2.date_time)
                      from tbl t2
                      where t1.device=t2.device
                     )
```

In case you switch over to a dbms version that supports window functions, use

```
select device,event_data,prev_event_data,date_time
from (select t.*
      ,lead(event_data) over(partition by device order by date_time) as next_event_data
      ,lag(event_data) over(partition by device order by date_time) as prev_event_data
      from tbl t
     ) t 
where next_event_data is null -- last row in the group which will be the row with latest date_time
```

Comment: Took me a while to test but this worked perfectly.  Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a correlated subquery in the `where`:

```
select e.*
from example e
where e.date_time = (select max(e2.date_time)
                     from example e2
                     where e2.device = e.device
                    );
```

If you know that the `id`s are inserted in order, then you can use `id` instead of `date_time` for the filtering.

This should have good performance if you have an index on `(device, date_time)`.

You can get the previous status by using a correlated subquery:

```
select e.*,
       (select e2.event_data
        from example e2
        where e2.device = e.device and
              e2.date_time < e.date_time
        order by e2.date_time desc
        limit 1
       ) as prev_event_data
from example e
where e.date_time = (select max(e2.date_time)
                     from example e2
                     where e2.device = e.device
                    );
```

EDIT:

If those are the only columns you need, then the `substring_index()`/`group_concat()` hack might work:

```
select max(id), device, max(date_time),
       substring_index(group_concat(event_data order by date_time desc), ',', 1) as last_event_data,
       substring_index(substring_index(group_concat(event_data order by date_time desc), ',', 2), ',', -1) as prev_event_data
from example
group by device;
```

In most other databases, you would just do this with the `lag()` function but most versions of MySQL do not support this.

Note that this depends on the `group_concat()` function.  By default, this has a maximum internal string length of 1028.  However, this is a settable parameter and can be made much larger.

Comment: How to get the previous event data from this query?