# How to query current state of all Objects in a event driven database table?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am currently implementing a blacklist feature for my application. Therefore I want to use a event based datatable, so I can also track, when a item has been blocked and by whom.

To give you a bit of a context: This is how the table looks like

```
id|object_id |object_type|change_time        |change_type|
--|----------|-----------|-------------------|-----------|
 0|1234567890|ITEM       |2019-04-29 15:12:42|BLACKLISTED|
 1|654321    |MATERIAL   |2019-04-29 15:14:19|BLACKLISTED|
 2|654321    |MATERIAL   |2019-04-29 15:14:58|CLEARED    |
```

As I am using spring and spring-data-jpa it is quite easy to get the current state of a single Item when querying for the first result ordered by time.

```
@Repository
public interface ItemFilterRepository extends JpaRepository<ItemFilterDpo, Integer> {

    ItemFilterDpo findFirstByObjectIdAndObjectTypeOrderByChangeTimeDesc(String objectId, ItemFilterObjectTypeDpo type);

}
```

However, I can't find a nice solution for showing all Items that are currently blocked.

So I had a look here in stack overflow and found an answer using subqueries in the sql ([SQL Query for current state of all entities in event table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48272331/sql-query-for-current-state-of-all-entities-in-event-table)).

```sql
select 
  object_id, object_type, change_time, change_type as last_modified
from 
  item_filter ife
where 
  ife.change_time = (
        select max(ife2.change_time)
        from item_filter ife2
        where ife.object_id=ife2.object_id
      )
```

That gives me the following result, which I can filter for `BLACKLISTED` afterwards:

```
object_id |object_type|change_time        |last_modified|
----------|-----------|-------------------|-------------|
1234567890|ITEM       |2019-04-29 15:12:42|BLACKLISTED  |
654321    |MATERIAL   |2019-04-29 15:14:58|CLEARED      |
```

To use that with spring-data, my first approach would be to create a view and query from that.

**I'd really like to know, whether there is a better approach using spring-data to query the current state of all objects in a event datatable.**

If an other framework suites better for my problem, I am happy to know.

---

Edit:
Using `distinct on` feels a bit better, however this doesn't solves my problem with spring-data.

```sql
select distinct on (object_id, object_type) 
  object_id, object_type, change_time, change_type as last_modified
from 
  item_filter bl
order by 
  object_id, object_type, change_time DESC;
```

Comment: Using `distinct on` is typically **much** faster in Postgres than using a sub-query for [tag:greatest-n-per-group] problems. But I guess your obfuscation layer won't allow to use that.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Thanks for pointing that out.